# printing sql query result in a single line

Tags: mysql

I have two columns (groupID, memberID) in table and I execute following mysql query

```
select `groupID` from `tbl_groupassign` where `memberID` = 'check1';
```

which prints column groupID but I want to show groupID in single row with each groupID separated by comma. For example I get following result by executing above query

> groupID
>
> group1
>
> group2

but I want show it as group1, group2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`groupID` SEPARATOR ',') FROM `tbl_groupassign` WHERE `memberID` = 'check1' GROUP BY `memberID`;
```

Comment: very fast reply. Thanks for the solution.